# Couldn't Generate the Client Library for the Endpoints API

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

The following commands are working fine:
- `mvn clean install`
- `mvn appengine:devserver`
- `mvn appengine:update`

But when I try the following command:
 `mvn -e appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib`

I get the following error (the command reinvent a JAVA_HOME).
thanks for the support

```
Aug 03, 2015 5:26:54 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/space2m/mvnworkspace/ovinto/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
API client library written to /home/space2m/mvnworkspace/ovinto/target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/ovinto-v1-java.zip
[INFO] BUILDING Endpoints Client Library from: /home/space2m/mvnworkspace/ovinto/target/endpoints-client-libs/ovinto/pom.xml
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java/bin/java
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.191 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-03T17:26:56+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/90M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.24:endpoints_get_client_lib (default-cli) on project ovinto: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.24:endpoints_get_client_lib failed: Build failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [so].

Answer (score 0):

based on my research there is an issue in mvn script (at least in my version of maven 3.2.1) which change JAVA_HOME into JAVA_HOME/bin/java
before running actual mvn command.

I just put into comment following line in mvn (linux)

```
#JAVA_HOME=`readlink -f "$JAVACMD" | sed "s:/jre/bin/java::"`
```

(it's around line 170)

and it works now.